# How can I fix dependency issue on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS Focal?

Tags: apt, package-management, sound, pulseaudio

I am not a really experienced user with Ubuntu dependencies management and I am faced with an issue I cannot solve my self.

My Ubuntu version is the following:

- OS Name: **Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS**
- OS Type: **64-bit**
- GNOME Version: **3.36.8**
- Windowing System: **X11**

When I try to install something new on my computer I get the following error:

```
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nomacs : Depends: libquazip5-1 (>= 0.7.3) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: nomacs-l10n (= 3.12.0+dfsg-3) but it is not going to be installed
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.10) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 is to be installed
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11)
 pulseaudio-module-jack : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and, then, if I try to execute the recommended command `apt --fix-broken install` I get the following output:

```
workstation@workstation $ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cdebootstrap debian-archive-keyring libc++1 libc++1-10 libc++abi1-10 libcg libcggl libdebian-installer-extra4 libdebian-installer4
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  pulseaudio
Suggested packages:
  pavumeter paman paprefs
The following packages will be upgraded:
  pulseaudio
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 320 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/816 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 421535 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11) over (1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.10) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/pulseaudio_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to create '/usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-aux.conf.dpkg-new' (while processing './usr/share/pulseaudio/alsa-mixer/paths/analog-input-aux.conf'): Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/pulseaudio_1%3a13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can anyone help with this situation?

## Update 1

After the recommendation of David to run the command `sudo apt autoremove` I get again the following error:

```
workstation@workstation $ sudo apt autoremove
[sudo] password for merianos: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 pulseaudio : Depends: libpulse0 (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.10) but 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 is installed
 pulseaudio-module-bluetooth : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11)
 pulseaudio-module-jack : Depends: pulseaudio (= 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11)
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

## Update 2

Upon suggestions made by @guiverc, I have run the `sudo apt update` and the errors / warnings I get are the following:

```
workstation@workstation $ sudo apt update
Hit:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:3 https://linux.teamviewer.com/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Hit:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cybermax-dexter/sdl2-backport/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Hit:6 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Ign:8 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/webdesigner/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:10 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:11 http://repo.vivaldi.com/stable/deb stable Release                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kxstudio-debian/apps/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:13 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                                                                                                               
Hit:14 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Hit:15 http://archive.canonical.com focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
Get:16 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease [1559 B]                                                                                         
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Hit:18 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:19 http://downloads.metasploit.com/data/releases/metasploit-framework/apt lucid InRelease                                                                                                                                                          
Get:20 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]                                                                                                                                                                             
Hit:21 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Hit:22 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                                                                                                          
Get:24 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [114 kB]                                                                                                                                             
Get:26 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease [2879 B]                                                                                                                                  
Hit:27 https://deb.beekeeperstudio.io stable InRelease                     
Hit:28 https://packagecloud.io/slacktechnologies/slack/debian jessie InRelease
Err:25 https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker InRelease                
  403  Forbidden [IP: 54.240.169.16 443]
Err:16 https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>
Err:26 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6DB5542C356545CF
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
E: Failed to fetch http://get.docker.io/ubuntu/dists/docker/InRelease  403  Forbidden [IP: 54.240.169.16 443]
E: The repository 'http://get.docker.io/ubuntu docker InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/Emulators:/Wine:/Debian/xUbuntu_18.04 ./ InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG DFA175A75104960E Emulators OBS Project <Emulators@build.opensuse.org>
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 6DB5542C356545CF
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:16 and /etc/apt/sources.list:45
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Packages (universe/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Translations (universe/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11 (universe/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons (universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target CNF (universe/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:18 and /etc/apt/sources.list:47
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:59 and /etc/apt/sources.list:80
```

Comment: Yes, is the second part of my question. When I run the `sudo apt --fix-broken install` I get a different error message.

Comment: When I do `sudo apt autoremove` I get again the first error I have on top of my question.

Comment: You've not provided your OS & release details, which is necessary to provide useful advice; however it appears as if you're using a *focal* system with outdated software lists (but you've not said what release you're using).  If that is true, you should `sudo apt update` & read the messages there as your packages shown in pastes are wrong for a *focal* system (they're outdated)  eg. `libpulse0 | 1:13.99.1-1ubuntu3.11 | focal-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, s390x`

Comment: @guiverc you are right. I just updated my question. Thank you :)

Comment: Your system is outdated - an updated 20.04 system will report itself as 20.04.3 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/08/27/ubuntu-20-04-3-lts-released/ shows the ISO release date, but installed systems upgraded to it about a fortnight before that date) - start with `sudo apt update` & look for errors, warnings or missing lines, as your software lists are outdated as per prior comment

Comment: @guiverc I have updated my question with the errors/warnings I have upon execution of the command `sudo apt update`. Unfortunately, as I said before, I cannot help a lot with the output as I don't understand what is this messages list :(

Comment: Your package management is in very bad shape. There are a lot of problems here that it's hard to tell you where to start. There are many things to fix. Your sources are very messy. Several are incompatible and for the wrong version of Ubuntu. Many of the PPAs may be outdated or no longer maintained.  It also seems that you have not not kept up with maintenance and you have not updated your system in a very very long time.  You should backup and remove unused or outdated sources and PPAs and remove all sources that aren't focal sources.

Comment: Be more judicious about what sources you add to your system. PPAs can [break your system](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for), especially when they are outdated. You should never add sources from another distro or another version of Ubuntu since this will cause conflicts. And you should always keep your system up-to-date. `sudo apt update` should be run before any other `apt` command so you are working with the current list of software and you should also `sudo apt upgrade` before adding/removing software

Comment: The bionic, xenial, groovy & eoan sources should not exist on your focal system

Comment: That your system still functions at all after so many years of random and wrong-version sources reflects great credit upon the skills and forethought of the Debian developers of apt.